# Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data for all JSON requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, networking, firewall

Some of my site users are unable to call any api endpoints successfully whether through AJAX or a direct GET request in the browser. All HTML pages work fine. They get the following error when hitting an API endpoint.

--

[image]

--

What can be the issue here? I am suspecting some kind of firewall/ISP/Network restriction may be causing this, but I am not sure. What can I do to debug the issue? I checked my server logs and the request is hitting my server and the right response is being sent back. I am using rails 3.

**UPDATE**
Figured out the issue. The client's firewall is blocking application/json content.

Answer (score 0):

The client's firewall is blocking all content of mime type `application/json`